# Azure Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, class-library

I have a `web` app (**ASP.NET** 5 **EF** 7) which is divided into several projects, among which there's one for the Identity model and one for other App Data models (both as class libraries). So in the **azure** web portal I have `2` servers (each with `1` `db`) created, one for app data and one for identity data.

When I try to register a new user I get the following error:

> [detailed error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLLyk.jpg)

The data connections are configured OK in the portal.

In the main project I have an `appsetting.json` file with

```
  "Data": {
    "DefaultIdentityConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=identityDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "DefaultAppDataConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=appDataDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

and in each class library project (`1` for identity and 1 for appdata) I have another `appsettings.json` file with the same `connection-strings`.

and the StartUp ConfigureServices looks like this:
and the `StartUp` `ConfigureServices` looks like this:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext < IdentityContext > (options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultIdentityConnection:ConnectionString"]))
    .AddDbContext < AppDataContext > (options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultAppDataConnection:ConnectionString"]));

services.AddIdentity < ApplicationUser, IdentityRole > (
        config => {
            ....
        })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores < IdentityContext > ()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

All is well on the local machine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obviously turned out to be my fault because I had the same connection strings defined in 2 additional appsettings.json files (1 for the identity project and 1 for the app data project) and each was referenced as a configuration file in it's parent project (instead of injecting the Configuration object from Startup, I created 1 per each project - which was a bad idea), and I guess this confused things.